# Webpack devServer proxy not working with Sapper

Tags: webpack, svelte, sapper

I have a **node** dev server running **Sapper** on `http://localhost:3000`, and I want all `/api/` requests proxy another local dev server written on python `http://localhost:8000/api/`

This worked perfectly for pure **Svelte**:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports.devServer = {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
        '/api/': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8000',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true
        }
    },
};
```

But does absolutely nothing with **Sapper** - just get default Sapper's 404 error

I guess it is somehow related with **Sapper**'s routing mechanism, but can not find how to deal with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sapper uses [Polka](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polka) server. Proxy can be configured using [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

**src/server.js**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

polka()
    .use('/api', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:8000' }))
    // other .use, .listen rules
```